# LibVlc android error loading MRL

Tags: android, video, libvlc

i am trying to use the vlc library to reproduce a video in my application.
I must be missing something because if i run the vlc-android application it works.
I thought it was a fault due to the file location but then i took the location string from the vlc app using the logging system but it doesn't work anyway.
Quite strange there must be some parameter to set before call `libvlc.playMRL(videoMedia.getMrl());`
This is my code, it basically initializes LibVLC and try to load a video from a path.

```
// Create a new media player
        libvlc = new LibVLC();
        libvlc.init(this);
        libvlc.setHardwareAcceleration(LibVLC.HW_ACCELERATION_DISABLED);
        libvlc.setSubtitlesEncoding("");
        libvlc.setAout(LibVLC.AOUT_OPENSLES);
        libvlc.setTimeStretching(true);
        libvlc.setVerboseMode(true);
        if(LibVlcUtil.isGingerbreadOrLater())
            libvlc.setVout(LibVLC.VOUT_ANDROID_WINDOW);
        else
            libvlc.setVout(LibVLC.VOUT_ANDROID_SURFACE);

        EventHandler.getInstance().addHandler(mHandler);
        holder.setKeepScreenOn(true);

        Media videoMedia = new Media(libvlc, "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20150513_005427.mp4");

        libvlc.playMRL(videoMedia.getMrl());
```

And this is the error i get:

> core input: open of `file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20150513_005427.mp4' failed
>   core input: Your input can't be opened
>   core input: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20150513_005427.mp4'. Check the log for details.

Comment: Hi, did you find any answer on this? I'm facing same issue.